# HTML How to keep divs touching each other

Tags: html, css

When I resize the window (in Firefox at least) then my divs separate from each other. How can I keep my divs touching each other nicely?

Bare in mind that the whole background image has to display fully, I have solutions where the background image goes behind the scroll bar but I don't want that.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.Div1 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/7NQ3IOt.jpg");
    background-size: 100%, 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 76.1vw;
    width: 100%;
}

.Div2 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/CjVMSqG.jpg");
    background-size: 100%, 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 169vw;
    width: 100%;
}

.Btns {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2.1vw;
    left: 16.5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Div1">
        <button class="Btns" style="top: 4.8vw">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Div2">
        <button class="Btns" style="top: 4.3vw">Button 1</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can u please explain more?

Comment: `display: inline-block`; is your friend.

Comment: @Sagar Kodte Basically the two Div background images need to touch each other exactly (there shouldn't be a white gap between the red and blue lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divs touch each others. But the height of background image of the first div is smaller than the div's height.

Remove comma from background-size rule: `background-size: 100% 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size:cover`. Is that what you want?
`cover` property is use to cover the entire container with background-image.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.Div1 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/7NQ3IOt.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 76.1vw;
    width: 100%;
}

.Div2 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/CjVMSqG.jpg");
    background-size: 100%, 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 169vw;
    width: 100%;
}

.Btns {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2.1vw;
    left: 16.5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Div1">
        <button class="Btns" style="top: 4.8vw">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Div2">
        <button class="Btns" style="top: 4.3vw">Button 1</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem I have found with cover is that the image gets lost behind the scroll bar, check your example. The blue image fits nicely but the red one gets lost.

Comment: Please check full page version. This is because of snippet issue and then change resolution by CTRL + mouse scroll.

Comment: Thanks but zooming in shouldn't be the solution to the problem I feel...

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo
Change `background-size: 100%, 100%;` to `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Remove the comma next to 100%